# How to check if SSH compression is enabled?

Tags: ssh, git, compression

I am experiencing severe slowdown in Git checkouts from VM. I've been told that one of the reasons may be SSH compression (either enabled or disabled). How to check that is the state of compression during checkouts?

The checkout is made by Ansible job if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `.ssh/config` file and/or create a ssh wrapper script:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh\nssh -v -v $*' > custom_ssh
chmod +x custom_ssh
GIT_SSH="./custom_ssh" git clone [...]
```

and check the debug output of ssh.